# Open existing file in OSX with RCP and register file type

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp, info.plist

I'm working on installers for a tool written in Java/Ecipse RCP and everything is working except two things I think could be related:

1) Open existing file. For some reason OSX doesn't provide the selected file as an argument like windows and linux does. How do I get osx to pass the path as an argument? or is there another way?

2) File type doesn't register properly. Double clicking an existing file with the extension opens the application as expected, but when I go "Open with" - "Other" the tool is greyed out, how do I make osx understand that the tool can open such files?

Here's the current Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>images/icons/macos.icns</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>2016 Company</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Tool description</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.2.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.2.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Tool</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>com.company.tool</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.utilities</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>tool</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.tool</string>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.company.tool.extension</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>ext</string>
            </dict>
            <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>images/icons/macos.icns</string>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>tool file</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <string>images/icons/macos.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>tool file</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.company.tool.extension</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```